# MySQL query using count() and if/case

Tags: mysql

I need to find the count of users who have filled the questionnaire on that day.

These are the total counts , i need counts per day.  Here is the picture of database:  http://www.upload.ee/image/3800828/pildike.png

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, COUNT(ANSWER_TIME) AS ARV FROM RESULT WHERE ANSWER_TIME IS NOT NULL GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY ARV DESC;
```

1. For example this gives me:

   - 32     2142
   - 143    1098
   - 26    979
   - 76    878

But i need like distinct rows, answer_day_of_week is from 1 to 7, depending on day and answer_time is TIMESTAMP. The statistics is been for 97 days and for example person 32 has filled it 2000+ times in 97 days, but i only need to count them once...

I thought to use if-elseif or while or case or some sort of subquery ? I have tried some queries but i always fail...

For example for one day i can have 15 rows from one person on 1. oct but have 0 rows on 2. oct , then it gives answer that he has filled the survey only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(ARV) AS ARV
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, DATE(ANSWER_TIME) AS ARV FROM RESULT WHERE ANSWER_TIME IS NOT NULL 
        ) A
        GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY ARV DESC;
```

Please try the above query

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sql query like this:

> SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, COUNT(ANSWER_TIME) AS ARV FROM RESULT WHERE DATE(ANSWER_TIME) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '97 DAYS') GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY ARV DESC;

Comment: This gives me syntax error... where date_sub() , there is and error near date_sub()

Comment: I'm sorry, I've correct the query. Especially the where condition.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, COUNT(ANSWER_TIME) AS ARV FROM RESULT WHERE DATE_SUB(ANSWER_TIME, INTERVAL 97 DAY)  GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY ARV DESC;
But this gives me exactly the same result as my first query ...

Comment: Please look at the edited post.
> SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, COUNT(ANSWER_TIME) AS ARV FROM RESULT WHERE ANSWER_TIME >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '97 DAYS') GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY ARV DESC;

Comment: It does not work , for person number 32, it gives less , but it is still 1970 or something... 
Also i googled and the syntax should be DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 97 DAY).
I think the problem is that the answer_time timestamp , is without hours and minutes ...
Here is a example of the table .... <http://www.upload.ee/image/3800928/pildike2.png>

Comment: I just edit the sql query by adding DATE function to ANSWER_TIME field. Please try it. And submit your query result.